# Ansible kerberos auth : user account is failing to connect node

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Auth has been changed from basics to kerberos and config changes has been made but in the controller. But while executing ping module the command is failing with below error.

Made necessary changes in /etc/krb5.conf controller machine. kinit works with user name

```py
testwinim.NORTHERNGATES.INTERNAL | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

> ansible -i /home/ansible/hosts win -m win_ping -e="ansible_ssh_port=5986, ansible_connection=winrm" command should give pass response rather getting failed

Answer (score 0):

Can you try passing the below one also as argument
`ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true`

Comment: `[win:vars]
ansible_user= Ansibleservice@NORTHERNGATES.INTERNAL
ansible_password= '27B#$$*(^%'
ansible_connection= winrm
ansible_winrm_transport= kerberos
#ansible_winrm_realm= NORTHERNGATES.INTERNAL
ansible_winrm_scheme= http
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation= ignore
ansible_port= 5985
#ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation= yes `--- Tried all the parameters in hosts file still the same error. We`re using **2.7 Ansible version**

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Issue was with NTP server where Ansible controller and Domain controller wasnt in sync. Post setting ntpd on the controller and changed to UTC format, Service account and playbooks were working as expected,